# Domain events with Rebus and eventlisteners in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, rebus

I have some RebusHandlers like:

```
public class CastleRebusHandler : IHandleMessages<CastleRebusMessage>
{
    ... (ctor injections from windsor)

    public void Handle(CastleRebusMessage message)
    {
        var myPoco = _session.Get<MyPoco>(1);
        myPoco.MethodThatRaiseDomainEvent();
    }
}
```

The Method `MethodThatRaiseDomainEvent` adds a domain event to an internal list as described [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/13/a-better-domain-events-pattern/).
 I have set up some `IPostUpdateEventListener` in NHibernate which will run thru the collection of domain events and dispatch each. I've made a class which to control `ISession` for Rebus on BeforeMessage and AfterMessage events. 
The domain dispatch event code run (as described in link), in the eventlisterners of `NHibernate = AfterMessage` in Rebus. Problem is what if an exception occurs here?

How can I move the message to the error queue of Rebus to signal a failure?

We are using the 0.83 version

Ken

Comment: Rebus should move message to error queue after n failed tries (5 by default). It can be configured as shown in here https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/wiki/Automatic-retries-and-error-handling . If exception occurs e.g in your handler, it is treated as fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebus has a unit of work mechanism that you should hook you session commit action into - you do it by using

```
Configure.With(...)
    .(...)
    .Events(e => e.AddUnitOfWorkManager(...))
    .(...)
```

where you can supply the uow manager that does the work. The unit of work manager's job is to create a `IUnitOfWork`, which is where you can invoke commit and rollback of your session's accompanying transaction.

I hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Thanks, so if an exception is thrown in the `AfterMessage` event, will that trigger an `Abort` in the UnitOfWork manager?

Comment: I think so, yes, but (without knowing all the details of your problem, of course) I think it would be more natural to perform the logic you have in `AfterMessage` now inside `Commit` of the unit of work

Comment: Yes, I implemented a class with `IUnitOfWork` and handled session management in that. Worked perfectly, and dropped the `AfterMessage` and `BeforeMessage` events